# Class 'CI_GridView' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\mgt\Master_Panel\system\core\Common.php on line 195

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am using Codeigniter3 and I have a GridView file which I placed in Library folder.

this is my GridView code;

```
<?php (defined('BASEPATH')) OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class GridView{

    private $data;
    private $headers;
    private $is_sortable;
    private $sort_columns;
    private $current_sort;
    private $show_checkbox;
    private $per_page;
    private $total_items;
    private $current_page;
    private $column_count;
    private $pagination_dots_threshold;
    private $search_url;
    private $deleteOption;
    private $formAction;
    private $formID;

    function __construct(){}

    public function init($config=array()){

        $default=array(
            "id"=>"companies",
            "css_table_classes"=>"table table-bordered table-striped table-hover",
            "data"=>array(),
            "headers"=>array(),
            "is_sortable"=>true,
            "sort_columns"=>array(),
            "current_sort"=>"",
            "show_checkbox"=>true,
            "per_page"=>20,
            "total_items"=>42,
            "current_page"=>1,
            "pagination_dots_threshold"=>20,
            "search_url"=>false,
            "deleteOption"=>true,
            "formAction"=>"",
            "formID"=>""
        );

        $final= $config + $default;

        foreach($final as $k=>$v){
            $this->{$k}=$v;
        }

        $positive = $negative = $this->negative_sort_columns=array();
        if(is_array($this->sort_columns) && count($this->sort_columns) > 0){
            foreach ($this->sort_columns as $col) {
                if(stripos($col,'!')!==false){
                    $negative[]=str_replace("!","",$col);
                }else{
                    $positive[]=$col;
                }
            }

            $this->sort_columns=$positive;
            $this->negative_sort_columns=$negative;
        }

    }
}
```

and I am calling this in my controller, like this,

```
$grid=load_class("GridView", $directory = 'libraries', $prefix = '');
```

But it showed me an error and said that  **Class 'CI_GridView' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\mgt\Master_Panel\system\core\Common.php on line 195**

Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: `$this->load->library('GridView');` instead of `load_class()`??

Comment: I tried that as well...but still got the same error

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `$this->load->library('GridView');` instead of `load_class()`.

And call its functions like: `$this->gridview->init($config);`

**Alternatively**, if you really want to use `load_class()` instead, you have to rename your class MY_GridView and save it to file by the same name - MY_GridView.php. And load it in your controller the same way you did - `$grid=load_class("GridView", 'libraries', '');`